# subprocess doesn't write the output file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess, gdal

I'm working with python in a jupyter notebook.

I want to execute the following command :

```
$ gdalbuildvrt tmp_merge files
```

with `tmp_merge` being an output file of the function and set to : `/home/prambaud/gfc_results/test/tmp_tile.vrt`
and `files` being all the tiles to merge in the `vrt` file set to :`/home/prambaud/gfc_results/test/tile_*.tif`

This function authorize the use of the wildcard.

To run it in my Jupyter notebook I use the `subprocess` module:

```py
command = [
    'gdalbuildvrt',
    '/home/prambaud/gfc_results/test/tmp_tile.vrt',
    '/home/prambaud/gfc_results/test/tile_*.tif'
]

process = subprocess.run(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
    #cwd=os.path.expanduser('~')
)
    
print(process. stdout)
```

as a result I obtain the following :

```
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

with no error messages. BUT the output file is not created. Does anyone know what could prevent the `subprocess.run` function to create and write in a file ?

**PS:**
I've also tried to run the command from the jupyter notebook with `!` and the same parameters and the tmp file have of course bee created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My command can only be executed from shell so using subprocess I need to add the `shell` keyword as :

```py
process = subprocess.run(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
    shell=True
)
```